# Какая разница между execute() и submit() у ExecutorService?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У `ExecutorService` есть два метода:

`void execute(Runnable command)` и

`Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`.

Какая между ними разница в поведении потоков, кроме возвращаемого значения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классах **ForkJoinPool**, **ThreadPoolExecutor** и **AbstractExecutorService** `submit` использует `execute`. В классе **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** `submit` и `execute` используют перегруженный метод`schedule`. Так что разницы нет.

`execute` это метод из интерфейса **Executor**

`submit` это метод из интерфейса **ExecutorService** который расширяет **Executor**.

Поскольку `submit` возвращает значение, то в нем происходит подготовка возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Если submit это обертка над execute, то что-то же она делает? Иначе зачем она вообще нужна?